# What is the difference between "column1 and(column2 or column3)" or "(column1 andcolumn2) or (column1 and column3) in an sql query run in mysql "

Tags: mysql

I m stuck in a situation where I needed  (column1 and column2) or (column1 or column3) from a table. So i implemented it as

```
    select * from mytable 
    where column1=x and (column2=y or column3=z)
```

But it fetches me some unneccesory rows and by implementing as

```
    select * from mytable 
    where (column1=x and column2=y) or (column1=x and column3=z)
```

It gives the result but i couldn't understand the diff between the two...please suggest

**EDIT (added details)**

Below I have explained my situation, Please check this,

Let me elaborate my situation :::

I have a table, say `clientdetails(int id, var firstname, var mobileno, var landlineno)` and I need to fetch those entries fetching values having unique `(firstname and  mobileno), or (firstname and landlineno)`. Either of the two `mobileno` or `landlineno` is mandatory.

so i wrote a query...

```
select id
from clientdetails 
where firstname = 'pooja' 
and (mobileno = mn or landlineno= ln )   
and mobileno  REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' 
and landlineno REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'"
```

Now ln or mn can be anything and say ''. Since there are many instances where the `firstname` is "pooja" without a landlineno. So it fetches that entries too which has no landlineno but different mobileno..

When I use the following query

```
select id
from clientdetails 
where (firstname = 'pooja' and mobileno = mn)
or (firstname = 'pooja' and landlineno= '' )
and mobileno REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
and landlineno REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'"
```

It fetches me the required rows.

Please explain me the execution format of these queries

Comment: Can you give your specific query, and an example of one of the "unnecessary" rows that it returned?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference - given three boolean variables `A, B, C`, then `A & (B | C) == (A & B) | (A & C)`

Comment: @Alnitak - but since there is a difference it means that there must be either something wrong with the version of MySQL he is using (in which case, being able to reproduce it would be helpful for the bug report) or else there is something wrong with the query that he is using (in the query or the table structure), but it isn't evident from the simplified version. What version of MySQL are you using user96 - and what does your table structure look like?

Comment: I suggest reading up on [De Mragan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: Alnitak is correct- there shouldn't be any difference, check your real code to ensure that you didn't have any errors before you translated it in this question.

Comment: @SeanVieira indeed it isn't evident, but it's exceedingly unlikely that such a trivial bug would be present in MySQL after all these years.

Comment: @Oled De Morgan's laws relate to _negation_ of logical operators and don't apply in this case.

Comment: *Chuckles* @Alnitak - I thought your comment was directed at Mark, not the questioner (hence the finger-wagging tone).  I apologize for my mistake!

Comment: Just a hunch but are there any nulls in Column1,Column2, or Column3? Or possible X,Y, or Z is a null?

Comment: @MarkByers: I have edited my question and described with an example,

Comment: @JohnFx: Ya any of the mobileno or landlineno may b null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Alnitak pointed out in comments, There shouldn't be any difference - given three boolean variables

```
A, B, C, then A & (B | C) == (A & B) | (A & C)
```

Well, I have tested both queries with simple example below both queries gives same result.

```
   create table emp_temp(id smallint(5),fname varchar(10),lname varchar(10));

    insert into emp_temp values (1,'jon','kam'),(2,'ish','dalviv'),(3,'ctn','gado'),
    (4,'jin','jain'),(5,'niraj','yadav');

    select * from emp_temp;

    mysql> select * from emp_temp;
    +------+-------+--------+
    | id   | fname | lname  |
    +------+-------+--------+
    |    1 | jon   | kam    |
    |    2 | ish   | dalviv |
    |    3 | ctn   | gado   |
    |    4 | jin   | jain   |
    |    5 | niraj | yadav  |
    +------+-------+--------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    Now comparing your two queries.

    select * from mytable 
    where column1=x and (column2=y or column3=z)

    select * from mytable 
    where (column1=x and column2=y) or (column1=x and column3=z)

    Consider

    column1 is id
    column2 is fname
    column3 is lname

    mysql> select * from emp_temp
        -> where id=1 and (fname='jon' or lname='yadav');
    +------+-------+-------+
    | id   | fname | lname |
    +------+-------+-------+
    |    1 | jon   | kam   |
    +------+-------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)


    mysql> select * from emp_temp 
        -> where (id=1 and fname='jon') or ( id=1 and lname='yadav');

    +------+-------+-------+
    | id   | fname | lname |
    +------+-------+-------+
    |    1 | jon   | kam   |
    +------+-------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)

    Both queries produces the same result.
```

Comment: Thanx for ur reply but, in my scenario any of the mobileno or landlineno may be null.
And in that case there are many entries having same firstname
and different mobileno no, but the landlineno may b null.
BUt I need to fetch unique clients according to unique fn and(mn or ln),
I hope u understood my problem..If not then plz let me know

Answer (score 1):

Are any of the columns `NULL`?

```
true AND unknown => false
true OR unknown => true
```

etc.

I did not see if all combinations of NULL would cause the two expressions to differ, but it seems a possible culprit.

Comment: ya any of the field can b null